# GitHub cherry-picking your change from master to release branch

Tags: git, github, release, pull-request, cherry-pick

I have GitHub repository with two branches

- master
- release

`master` is where latest code resides.
`release` branch is used to release the particular version of software to customer.

Every developer creates a new branch for his `feature` development and when it is done, a new pull request is created for merge to `master`.

On pull request all the tests are run.
If it is green, the PR is merged.

Now if some `hotfix` is to be delivered into the `release` branch there are two options:

1. Cherry-pick the change to `release` branch
2. Create another pull request from `feature` branch to `release` branch

The first one has advantage of better history, as one can track if particular change is included in `release` or not.

But with cherry-pick no pull request is created, so there is no place to run test before the changes reach `release` branch, which at times can be risky.

What is better way to deal with this situation?

Comment: This seems like a candidate for closing-as-opinion-based...